# Hadoop python job gives me an error when the code using echo works perfectly

Tags: python, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I am trying to find the solution to stanford's CS246 2014 hw solution of the most popular guy on campus.

I keep running into the error "Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1"

My python code for the mapper is

```
{#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

ID = None
fcount = 0
count = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()

    words = line.split("        ")
    ID,friends = words
    fcount = len(friends.split(","))
    #count = fcount * -1
#for i in friends:
#               if i != ','

#               fcount +=1

    print "%d\t%s" %(fcount,ID)

}
```

and my reducer code is

{

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

ID = None
fcount = 0
count = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()

    words = line.split("        ")
    ID,friends = words
    fcount = len(friends.split(","))
    #count = fcount * -1
#for i in friends:
#               if i != ','

#               fcount +=1

    print "%d\t%s" %(fcount,ID)
```

}

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This ran perfectly by the way, echo "$(cat file.txt)" | python map.py | sort -k2 | python reduc.py

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. The error happened because of the two different versions of python. I had python 3 on my system and python 2 on the hadoop system.